# issue for loop bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have this code:

```
folder="test folder"
fil=`find "$folder" -type f -printf '%p %s\n'`
IFS=$'\n'
echo $fil
```

in the folder I have two files and after execution I get

```
file1.txt 120
file2.txt 9
```

My problem is this code:

```
for i in $fil
do

  echo "$i"

done
```

using a counter in the for loop I discovered that it is executed only one time and not two time(because there is 2 string separated by '\n') and when "echo" is executed I get:

```
file1.txt 120
file2.txt 9
```

I want that the "i" variable assumes "file1.txt 120" the first time , and the second time "file2.txt 9"

Why it doesn't separate the line by '\n'?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Unless you somehow change the value of $IFS between setting `fil` and the `for` loop, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: to you then the for loop is executed two times (in the case are 2 files )?

Answer (score 1):

Don't grab `find` output and then loop. Use [`process substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
while read -r file size; do
  echo "file=$file"
  echo "size=$size"
done < <(find "$folder" -type f -printf '%p %s\n')
```

Comment: can you explain this code? in particular the "done <<(find "$folder" -type f -printf '%p %s\n')"

Comment: That is called process substitution. Check my link in the answer for examples and detailed explanation.

Comment: Make sure you're using `BASH`.

Comment: I resolved this issue, but I don't understand why before code(mine) isnt work

Comment: That's not the correct way do run a loop over a command's output. In the worst case you can do: `find "$folder" -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | while read -r file; do   echo "$file"; done`

Comment: I have a problem because on every file(getting from find command) I have to execute cut command and gawk command, but I  do not know how to do it with this new way

Comment: You can use updated script for that, no need of `cut` or `awk`